# AngularJs routing is not working properly and bootstrap also not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, angularjs-routing

When i click on add button then i would like show message which is in AddController but routing is not working here i am going to give some of the screenshot and bootstrap also not working.

**demo.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);
  myApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/Add', {
        templeteUrl: 'View/add.html',
        controller: 'AddController'
      }).
      when('/Edit', {
        templeteUrl: 'View/edit.html',
        controller: 'EditController'
      }).
      when('/Delete', {
        templeteUrl: 'View/delete.html',
        controller: 'DeleteController'
      }).
      when('/Home', {
        templeteUrl: 'View/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/Home'
      });
   }]);
```

and now here is my **index.html** code

```
<link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="scripts/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="demo.js"></script>
```

```
<div class="container">

    <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-light">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#/Home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/Add">Add</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/Edit">Edit</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/Delete">Delete</a></li>
        </ul>

    </nav>
    <div ng-view>

    </div>
</div>
```

Now **Addcontroller**

```
myApp.controller("AddController", function ($scope) {
  $scope.message = "In Add view";
});
```

Comment: what is not working ? any error?

Comment: When i click on add i want message "In Add view " but it didn't route and dosen't show any error if you wish to see browser url then i wil provide you.

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle of this, it will be useful in debugging.

Comment: Your fiddle is broken.  Please ensure that your examples actually work, demonstrate the problem you are having, and are free from other errors.  In this case, you aren't even loading the angular script, but when it's added, other errors related to the controller appear as well.

Comment: @Claies  problem is when i click on Home it will give me 404 error. and sorry for jsfiddle i am using it first time

Comment: @RonakDumaniya did the answer help

Comment: Yup working perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues in the provided Fiddle link, but they are not available in the code you provided.

I have modified the routers and check the below working app.

```
myapp.config(['$routeProvider',
 function ($routeProvider) {
     $routeProvider.
     when('/add', {
         templateUrl: 'add.html',
         controller: 'addcontroller'
     }).
      when('/edit', {
          templateUrl: 'edit.html',
          controller: 'editcontroller'
      }).
      when('/delete', {
          templateUrl: 'delete.html',
          controller: 'deletecontroller'
      }).
      when('/home', {
          templateUrl: 'home.html',
          controller: 'homecontroller'
      }).
     otherwise({
         redirectto: '/home'
     });
 }]);
```

**[WORKING PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/Hn1jbE0ozDdRJXjFvMj3?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

Try remove the # from `<a href="#/Home">` and try again.

Answer (score -1):

To navigate routes the Angular way you should use **ui-sref** instead of **href**, so in your case:

```
<li class="active"><a ui-sref='Home'>Home</a></li>
<li><a ui-sref="Add">Add</a></li>
<li><a ui-sref="Edit">Edit</a></li>
<li><a ui-sref="Delete">Delete</a></li>
```

Read more here: https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/0.3.1/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref